# Fontawesome icons aren't showing up

Tags: html, css, icons

I am trying to use fontawesome 5 icons. My kit is from 4 so I'm not sure if thats the issue. any help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="chasebiscamp.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/68e7b84e8d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>CB</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        
            <button class="nav" id="profile_tab">Profile</button>
            <button class="nav" id="chat_tab">Chat</button>
            <button class="nav" id="friends_tab">Friends</button>
            <button class="nav" id="gallery_tab">Gallery</button>           
            <button class="nav" id="settings_tab">Settings</button>

    </nav>

    <p><i class="fa-solid fa-user" style="color: #000000;"></i></p>

    <div class="content_body" id="profile">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>

    

</body>

</html>
```

its pretty self explainatory.

Comment: Yes, the fact that you are trying to use v5 icons from a v4 kit is your problem. You need to use a v5 kit to access v5 icons

Answer (score 1):

Simply add "fa" in classlist

```
<p><i class="fa fa-solid fa-user" style="color: #000000;"></i></p>
```

[Example working](https://codepen.io/lefede/pen/ZEqGbGb)

Answer (score -1):

It Should Be A Problem in Your Root Directory And Try It With Nodejs